# How to get TotalSold/Year in Northwind?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing some exercises in T-SQL with [Northwind database](http://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/releases/view/71634) , I should get the TotalSold/Year 
    SUM(OrderDetails.UnitPrice * OrderDetails.Quantity) 
for each company, what I have done so far is to get the TotalSold for each company or to get the sold for each order, but no idea how to get the TotalSold/Year.

```
USE Northwind
GO

SELECT C.CompanyName, O.OrderDate,
   SUM(OD.UnitPrice * OD.Quantity) AS TotalSold
FROM Customers AS C
INNER JOIN Orders AS O
   ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
INNER JOIN [Order Details] AS OD
   ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
GROUP BY O.OrderDate, C.CompanyName
GO
```

the result is

```
CompanyName         OrderDate                   TotalSold
Alfreds Futterkiste 1997-08-25 00:00:00.000     1086.00
Alfreds Futterkiste 1997-10-03 00:00:00.000     878.00
Alfreds Futterkiste 1997-10-13 00:00:00.000     330.00
Alfreds Futterkiste 1998-01-15 00:00:00.000     851.00
Alfreds Futterkiste 1998-03-16 00:00:00.000     491.20
Alfreds Futterkiste 1998-04-09 00:00:00.000     960.00
...
```

any idea or clue to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use function `YEAR` instead of the order date itself.

```
USE Northwind
GO

SELECT C.CompanyName, YEAR(O.OrderDate) AS [Year],
   SUM(OD.UnitPrice * OD.Quantity) AS TotalSold
FROM Customers AS C
INNER JOIN Orders AS O
   ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
INNER JOIN [Order Details] AS OD
   ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
GROUP BY YEAR(O.OrderDate), C.CompanyName
GO
```